# The collada model looks strange (three.js)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, collada

The collada model looks strange in three.js. A screenshot:

[image: police]

The code is very simple, nothing special:

```
loader.load( 'models/police_car.dae', function ( collada ) {
  dae = collada.scene;

  init();
});
```

I downloaded the model from google sketchup warehouse. [[link](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=ce77b7e28b298ce21ab9df4be75138d0&prevstart=0)]

I have no idea what is the problem, because I'm new in three.js. Should I call a function to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

I think this is happening because the back faces are not being rendered. COLLADA has no way to specify whether a face should be double sided or not. Google Earth uses this method to export this information:

```
<extra>
  <technique profile="GOOGLEEARTH">
    <double_sided>1</double_sided>
  </technique>
</extra>
```

Three.js uses an attribute on an object called `doubleSided` to indicate if the face is double sided, but the ColladaLoader.js does not look for the `<extra>` tag to set the property. You should file a bug with three.js to add support for it.

**EDIT:** This appears to be fixed on the dev branch. Here's what I get loading this model:

[image]

You can clearly see the dashboard of the car inside through the partially-transparent window.

Comment: so there is no bug, I should just use the dev version of dae loader?

Comment: thanks. But the half-transparent window is blinking, and the car was rotated.

Comment: No idea, why the partially transparent window blinking, and the car rotated?

Comment: I don't think I noticed any blinking