# Collada model transparency not loading in three.js

Tags: transparency, three.js, collada

I have a similar issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540925/the-collada-model-looks-strange-three-js), using the same model, also loaded with the Collada loader.

The windows of the car are not displayed as transparent in three.js. You cannot see through them.

After digging through the three.js object data structures, it looks like the material for the window has opacity = 1 and transparent = false set on it.

I tried both with the release and with the dev version of three.js, as advised in the above referenced post but without any luck.

I also tried setting the opacity to 0.3 and transparent to true by hand in the material object (in debugger) and the transparency appears ! (although with some flickering).

Any idea what is wrong ? Is it a Collada loader problem ?

UPDATE: same problem on a much simpler model:

[screenshot of the problem](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-96O4jsS_v8M/UDtKbjQkKuI/AAAAAAAAA0Y/MzSJ1byyRiA/s600/ColladaProblem.png)

[link to the SketchUp model](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=9b45fb1aeace9a85aa41fd658ab36e83)

Thank you

Martin

Comment: Can you share the problematic model?

Comment: Follow the link at the beginning of the post, the linked post references the model. I will try to create a simpler model too because this transparency thing seems to be pretty consistent in Sketchup. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question with a much simpler model (cube inside of transparent cube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this and it's working for me. I took the model from [open3dhub](http://open3dhub.com/view/jterrace/us_police_car.dae/0) and imported it into [ThreeFab](http://blackjk3.github.com/threefab/) and then exported it to [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5sS/show/)([source](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5sS/)). I still see the flickering (that's a separate problem). This is on three.js from master.

[image]

Comment: And the Collada loader from master too I guess ?

Comment: Could you try with the SketchUp model I referenced above (cube in a transparent cube). I am starting to believe that it's the SketchUp export to Collada that does something weird. The Collada file has this for the "transparent" material:

'<transparent opaque="RGB_ZERO">
<color>0.6980392 0.6980392 0.6980392 0.6980392</color>
</transparent>
<transparency><float>1.0000000</float></transparency>'

Comment: That seems to be it. If I set <transparency><float>0.3</float></transparency> in the collada file the I see what I expect in three.js (a transparent cube).
@mrdoob
So this is either SketchUp not saving the material transparency like it should, or the Collada parser not importing it properly. I am not a Collada specialist so I do not know if <transparent><color>0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69</color></transparent><transparency><float>1.0000000</float></transparency> is a good way of saying "I want a transparent cube". It does not look to be the simplest one :-)

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know if this is a ColladaLoader bug, a SketchUp issue or a bizarre feature of the Collada spec but I found an easy enough workaround:

Edit the Collada file by hand, find the  tag and set its value by hand to 0.3 or anything you want instead of 1.

Not perfect but workable.